# firebase_database online / offline status

Tags: flutter

How can we determine whether our flutter app is online or offline when using firebase and the flutter-fire firebase_database plugin?

This blog post (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html) shows using the '.info/connected' child to get an Event when the app goes online/offline. However it only seems to trigger on app startup once and thats it.

I'm using this:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    print('Setting up the connected handler');
    final amOnline = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('.info/connected');
    _amOnlineSubscription = amOnline.onValue.listen((Event event) {
      print('EVENT has occured');
    });
  }
```

Maybe there is a better way to determine online/offline status? What I'm trying to do is avoid a sign-in page when the device is offline. Yet force a sign-in once it becomes connected to firebase again...

Comment: Well I've just found out the above code does actually work when on a real phone. I was testing in the simulator and turning off my laptops wifi but for some reason that doesn't register with firebase as being no-connected.

Comment: I've also found this flutter plugin that allows you to subscribe to a stream letting you know of connectivity status: connectivity. I'll leave this question here for a bit in case someone knows of a better or more appropriate way of doing this...

Comment: Hi Jason, you talk about a plugin, but what plugin? Can you provide an answer how you manage this please since I think you might have to do a Observer?

Comment: It’s in my second comment above. The plugin is called “connectivity”.

Answer (score 0):

I use [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) plugin on my app to check if the app has active network connection. This way, you won't need to use firebase_database just to check the device's connectivity.

You can add this on the app's initState()

```dart
@override
initState() {
  super.initState();

  subscription = Connectivity().onConnectivityChanged.listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
    // Check connectivity status
  })
}
```

and make sure to cancel the subscription once done.

```dart
@override
dispose() {
  super.dispose();

  subscription.cancel();
}
```